# "Stokes’ theorem can be generalized to piecewise smooth surfaces" -How

Tags: vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

Stokes’ theorem can be generalized to piecewise smooth surfaces, like the union of sides of a polyhedron. Here, we take the integral over the sides as the sum of integrals over each individual side.

Would anyone please help me to understand the sentences.
Stokes' theorem

$$\int_C f \cdot dr = \int\int_S (\nabla \times f) \cdot  n\, dS.
$$
Second sentence: "Here, we take the integral over the sides as the sum of integrals over each individual side." what does it mean... Is it "**Here, we take the surface integral over the sides as the sum of surface integrals over each individual side.**"...does it mean surface integral as $\int\int_{S} (\nabla \times f) \cdot  n\, dS= \sum_i\int\int_{S_i} (\nabla \times f) \cdot  n\, dS
$

Comment: Do you know what a piecewise smooth surface is? Do you know what it means to integrate a vector field over a piecewise smooth surface?

Comment: @littleO yes I know  piecewise smooth surface like  a parallelepiped.   In that case $\int_C f \cdot dr = \sum_i\int\int_{S_i} (\nabla \times f) \cdot  n\, dS.
$

Comment: @littleO "Here, we take the integral over the sides as the sum of integrals over each individual side." what does it mean... Is it "Here, we take the surface integral over the sides as the sum of surface integrals over each individual side."...does it mean surface integral as $ \int\int_{S} (\nabla \times f) \cdot  n\, dS= \sum_i\int\int_{S_i} (\nabla \times f) \cdot  n\, dS$